# how to route only private network through VPN openvpn?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I use pivpn to access a private network with specific services. This network has a dns and a lot of rules not allowing some simple website such as youtube or google. Since pivpn is by default in full tunneling all my traffic goes through my vpn network and I cannot do things like watching a youtube video or do some google search. I would like to route only my vpn connection through the vpn and let all others actions goes through the client network. How can I enable this kind of split tunneling ?

Here is my `/etc/openvpn/server.conf`

```
dev tun
proto tcp
port X
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued/VPN_28154d4a-2d8f-42b8-b083-a16948349746.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/VPN_28154d4a-2d8f-42b8-b083-a16948349746.key
dh none
ecdh-curve secp521r1
topology subnet
server X.X.X.X 255.255.255.0
# Set your primary domain name server address for clients
push "dhcp-option xxxx.com"
push "dhcp-option DNS X.X.X.X"
push "block-outside-dns"
# Override the Client default gateway by using 0.0.0.0/1 and
# 128.0.0.0/1 rather than 0.0.0.0/0. This has the benefit of
# overriding but not wiping out the original default gateway.
push "redirect-gateway def1"
client-to-client
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
keepalive 15 120
remote-cert-tls client
tls-version-min 1.2
 tls-crypt /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ta.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
user openvpn
group openvpn
persist-key
persist-tun
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20
status-version 3
syslog
verb 3
#DuplicateCNs allow access control on a less-granular, per user basis.
#Remove # if you will manage access by user instead of device.
#duplicate-cn
# Generated for use by PiVPN.io
```

Do you know how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is being routed via the VPN because your configuration *requests* this:

```
# Override the Client default gateway by using 0.0.0.0/1 and
# 128.0.0.0/1 rather than 0.0.0.0/0. This has the benefit of
# overriding but not wiping out the original default gateway.
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

Remove the "`redirect-gateway`" option and OpenVPN will return to the default behavior of routing just the VPN's own network (i.e. the X.X.X.X/255.255.255.0 network). If individual client configs have this option, make sure to remove it from there as well.

After making that change, you can route specific additional networks through the VPN by adding `route` options, e.g. pushed from the server to all clients:

```
push "route 192.168.7.0 255.255.255.0 vpn_gateway"
push "route 192.168.11.0 255.255.255.0 vpn_gateway"
```